# Mobipocket Creator Equivalent For Linux

Tags: linux, conversion, ebook

I'm a Kindle DX owner and I normally download some free PDFs from the internet, but I prefer to read then using the PRC format. As I'm a Linux user, I can't use Mobipocket Creator, then I want to ask for a alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux

Free reader, library manager and converter. Works on all platforms and inter-converts all formats. Supports Kindle, Sony, Bookeen etc.

It's actually much nicer than mobi and I found it by searching for ebook in the Ubuntu repository.

Answer (score 1):

the only possibility is to install on wine mobipocket reader and the run it to convert your pdfs to prc. If the pdf has a highly complicated structure, as background images the best should be use mobipocket creator to extract the images and then to make a prc without these images. But mobipocket creator doesn't run in wine. So you can install mobipocket creator using a virtual machine, but you need a lot of virtual memory if the pdf is too big or has a lot of pages (for example 900 or more...).

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy, but not straightforward.

Install AbiWord.  Open the PDF and copy all the text into Abiword. Save As, and choose the PalmDoc format.  This is actually the MobiPocket format and can be read by the MobiPocket Reader on my BlackBerry.  Haven't tested it on the Kindle, not owning one, but it should work.

Alternatively you could use pdftoabw (from the poppler-utils package in Ubuntu and Debian) to convert the PDF directly to AbiWord format, which might preserve formatting/images better than copy-paste.